# Synonymize tags about calculated columns

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are several tags about calculated columns; as far as I can see, there's no difference between how they are applied. Should they be synonymized, with [calculated-column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column) as the master tag?

- [calculated-column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column) (990 questions)
- [calculated-column-formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculated-column-formula) (562 questions)
- [calculatedfield](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculatedfield) (20 questions, no tag wiki/excerpt)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, Glorfindel for this hint.

We have merged the `calculatedfield` tag with `calculated-column` as a master tag, so if someone asks a general question about the **calculated column,** he should use the `calculated-column` tag. but if his question is specifically related to the **calculated column formula**, he should use `calculated-column-formula` tag.